# processing multiple data in matlab at once

Tags: matlab, loops

I have loaded a set of 50 files into matlab workspace. (from `data1` to `data50`). 
The size of each one is `721*176`. I want to extract only the first 144 lines of each data and store it in another one.

For example:

```
newData1 = data1(1:144,:);
```

My question is: How can I do this using a loop to process all data at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you store the data.

The best way in your case would be 3D array:

First, allocate the array (As @HighPerformanceMark points out correctly):

```
data = zeroes(721,176,50);
```

Then, populate it with values:

```
data(:,:,1)  =  read('firstFile.bmp');
data(:,:,2)  =  read('secondFile.bmp');
...

data(:,:,50) = ...
```

In that case, just use the following selection:

```
data(1:144,:,:)
```

---

Another plausible way to store the data is cell array. It is useful since 3D array cannot handle different size matrixes.

```
 data{1} = read('firstFile.bmp');
 data{2} = read('secondFile.bmp');
 ...
```

In this case, use `cellfun` :

```
 selection = cellfun(@(x) {x(1:144,:)}, data);
```

---

If you still insist on storing the data in separate variables rather than in an array, you can use `eval`. That is the least recommended way.

```
 for i=1:50
    eval(' selection{i} = data%d',i)
 end
```

Comment: Always worthwhile, if sizes are known in advance, creating an array of zeroes, in this case `data = zeroes(721,176,50)`, and then loading it as you suggest.